# Xcode failed to download app records from App Store Connect. There was an unexpected status code: 401

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store, apple-m1, testflight

[image]

error while uploading on testflight
Error Downloading App Information
Xcode failed to download app records from App Store Connect. There was an unexpected status code: 401.
account is already signed in my xcode account.

## in error log it showing

**2024-03-12 08:30:59 +0000 [MT] Rejected distribution method <IDEDistributionMethodAppStoreDistributionVisionOS: 0x60005e078460> because it doesn't support distributing archive**